# Parsing JSON content into array (Swift3)

Tags: ios, json, swift, wordpress, xcode8

I'm new to JSON and i'm trying to store multiple values in variable.

Here I have sample output I got from my site

```
2016-12-04 22:17:53.137949 API Demo[739:12497] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2016-12-04 22:17:53.142094 API Demo[739:12497] [] ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed
2016-12-04 22:17:53.142577 API Demo[739:12497] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2016-12-04 22:17:53.145324 API Demo[739:12497] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.20.4
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x00000001073a2682 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010767f932 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3100
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010765d4f4 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010765c511 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010765b270 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010767644d nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000107675e7c nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010768dae5 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010711f980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001071490cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107126e6b _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107127b9f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010712a3b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010712a08b _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001074f24de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001074f0341 start_wqthread + 13
(
        {
        "_links" =         {
            about =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post";
                }
            );
            author =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1";
                }
            );
            collection =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
                }
            );
            curies =             (
                                {
                    href = "https://api.w.org/{rel}";
                    name = wp;
                    templated = 1;
                }
            );
            replies =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=56";
                }
            );
            self =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/56";
                }
            );
            "version-history" =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/56/revisions";
                }
            );
            "wp:attachment" =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=56";
                }
            );
            "wp:term" =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=56";
                    taxonomy = category;
                },
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=56";
                    taxonomy = "post_tag";
                }
            );
        };
        author = 1;
        categories =         (
            3
        );
        "comment_status" = open;
        content =         {
            protected = 0;
            rendered = "A huge alligator snapping turtle got stuck in a blocked drain pipe in Houston, Texas.\n";
        };
        date = "2016-12-04T23:32:08";
        "date_gmt" = "2016-12-04T20:32:08";
        excerpt =         {
            protected = 0;
            rendered = "A huge alligator snapping turtle got stuck in a blocked drain pipe in Houston, Texas.\n";
        };
        "featured_media" = 0;
        format = standard;
        guid =         {
            rendered = "http://dpfqatar.com/?p=56";
        };
        id = 56;
        link = "http://dpfqatar.com/alligator-snapping-turtles-great-escape/";
        meta =         {
        };
        modified = "2016-12-04T23:32:29";
        "modified_gmt" = "2016-12-04T20:32:29";
        "ping_status" = open;
        slug = "alligator-snapping-turtles-great-escape";
        sticky = 0;
        tags =         (
        );
        title =         {
            rendered = "Alligator snapping turtle’s great escape";
        };
        type = post;
    },
        {
        "_links" =         {
            about =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post";
                }
            );
            author =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1";
                }
            );
            collection =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
                }
            );
            curies =             (
                                {
                    href = "https://api.w.org/{rel}";
                    name = wp;
                    templated = 1;
                }
            );
            replies =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=54";
                }
            );
            self =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/54";
                }
            );
            "version-history" =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/54/revisions";
                }
            );
            "wp:attachment" =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=54";
                }
            );
            "wp:term" =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=54";
                    taxonomy = category;
                },
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=54";
                    taxonomy = "post_tag";
                }
            );
        };
        author = 1;
        categories =         (
            3
        );
        "comment_status" = open;
        content =         {
            protected = 0;
            rendered = "Now don\U2019t worry\U200a-\U200ait\U2019s not shrieked amidst some kind of panicked, cold sweat. I\U2019m not having nightmares about search engines, or even the prolonged suffering of Google+ (though someone surely should be).\n";
        };
        date = "2016-12-04T23:31:00";
        "date_gmt" = "2016-12-04T20:31:00";
        excerpt =         {
            protected = 0;
            rendered = "Now don\U2019t worry\U200a-\U200ait\U2019s not shrieked amidst some kind of panicked, cold sweat. I\U2019m not having nightmares about search engines, or even the prolonged suffering of Google+ (though someone surely should be).\n";
        };
        "featured_media" = 0;
        format = standard;
        guid =         {
            rendered = "http://dpfqatar.com/?p=54";
        };
        id = 54;
        link = "http://dpfqatar.com/okay-google-you-need-a-cuter-name/";
        meta =         {
        };
        modified = "2016-12-04T23:31:00";
        "modified_gmt" = "2016-12-04T20:31:00";
        "ping_status" = open;
        slug = "okay-google-you-need-a-cuter-name";
        sticky = 0;
        tags =         (
        );
        title =         {
            rendered = "Okay Google, you need a cuter name";
        };
        type = post;
    },
        {
        "_links" =         {
            about =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post";
                }
            );
            author =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1";
                }
            );
            collection =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
                }
            );
            curies =             (
                                {
                    href = "https://api.w.org/{rel}";
                    name = wp;
                    templated = 1;
                }
            );
            replies =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=52";
                }
            );
            self =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/52";
                }
            );
            "version-history" =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/52/revisions";
                }
            );
            "wp:attachment" =             (
                                {
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=52";
                }
            );
            "wp:term" =             (
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=52";
                    taxonomy = category;
                },
                                {
                    embeddable = 1;
                    href = "http://dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=52";
                    taxonomy = "post_tag";
                }
            );
        };
        author = 1;
        categories =         (
            7
        );
        "comment_status" = open;
        content =         {
            protected = 0;
            rendered = "Apple has acknowledged for the first time that it is investing in building a self-driving car.\nIn a letter to US transport regulators, Apple said it was “excited about the potential of automated systems in many areas, including transportation”\n";
        };
        date = "2016-12-04T23:30:05";
        "date_gmt" = "2016-12-04T20:30:05";
        excerpt =         {
            protected = 0;
            rendered = "Apple has acknowledged for the first time that it is investing in building a self-driving car. In a letter to US transport regulators, Apple said it was “excited about the potential of automated systems in many areas, including transportation”\n";
        };
        "featured_media" = 0;
        format = standard;
        guid =         {
            rendered = "http://dpfqatar.com/?p=52";
        };
        id = 52;
        link = "http://dpfqatar.com/apple-reveals-self-driving-car-plans/";
        meta =         {
        };
        modified = "2016-12-04T23:30:05";
        "modified_gmt" = "2016-12-04T20:30:05";
        "ping_status" = open;
        slug = "apple-reveals-self-driving-car-plans";
        sticky = 0;
        tags =         (
        );
        title =         {
            rendered = "Apple reveals self-driving car plans";
        };
        type = post;
    }
)
```

Here is my code:

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.dpfqatar.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else {

            if let urlContent = data {

                do {

                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    print(jsonResult)


                } catch {

                    print("JSON Processing Failed")

                }  }  }  }

    task.resume()
```

How to print both `id` & `title` in this example? I tried so many methods but nothing worked for me.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: Your sample output is not a proper json.

Comment: I used Postman it is a google app can retrive data as json from the sites which build by wordpress after you install (WP rest api) plugin

Comment: @AmrIsreb: haven't you removed some lines? It seems like you forgot to remove some commas after you removed the lines. Your JSON is actually not valid. Please check [JSON linter](http://jsonlint.com/) with your original data.

Comment: The data you posted looks more like the iOS format for a container object than JSON. Is what you put in your question the output of the code you show? If so, it's not JSON, it's the display format for an array.

Comment: I upload the output on a file on dropbox. Thanks all of you really for your effort

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks** for all your help, I found the answer after deep search,

```
for anItem in jsonResult as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
let postID = anItem["id"] as! Int
Print(postID)}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you have an array with one element, a dictionary.

You could extract the `id` and `title` from your data like this:

```
if let arrayOfDicts = jsonResult as [[String: AnyObject]],
    let obj = arrayOfObjects.first,
    let id = obj["id"] as? String,
    let titleDict as obj["title"] as? [String: String],
    let title = titleDict["rendered"] {
  print("id = \(id), title = \(title)")
} else {
  print("Error extracting data from JSON container object")
}
```

(Note that I wrote that code in the SO editor. It likely contains a minor syntax error or two. You will need to clean it up yourself. )

Comment: Posting an answer with syntax errors in response to a novice swift programmer will likely cause confusion rather than actually assist the user asking the question.

Comment: I'm on an iPad, and don't have the ability to test the code. I disagree with you. Providing general guidance that the OP can use to learn how to approach the problem has a lot of value. The OP will learn more by understanding HOW to solve the problem that by copy-pasting somebody else's  ill-understood code into his app.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I tried your code, I delete the title part and kept on Id, when execute it giving me "cannot-subscript-a-value-of-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-string". I try to search over internet but nothing was good.